# Compositor nodes are ignored when rendering the classroom or the barber shop demo files in Blender 2.8

Tags: python, rendering, node-editor

I am trying to render a scene and its depth map using the Python APIs of Blender 2.8. I created a rendering node and connected its Image and Depth fields to two Output nodes, writing to PNG and EXR, respectively.

I managed to render with Blender 2.8 many scenes created with Blender versions older than 2.8. However, when I try to render the Blender 2.8 classroom or barber shop demos, I get no output. Basically the nodes are ignored.

The classroom file can be found at `https://www.blender.org/download/demo-files/`
and the script that I am using is the one below.

Thanks in advance for any help :)

```
import bpy
import os
import numpy as np

# Remove all the cameras in the scene.
bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
for i, item in enumerate(bpy.data.objects):
    if item.type == 'CAMERA':
        bpy.data.objects[i].select_set(True)
        bpy.ops.object.delete()

# Create a new camera. Like every newly created object, the camera is automatically assigned to `bpy.context.object`.
bpy.ops.object.camera_add()
cam = bpy.context.object

# Rename the new camera (not necessary).
cam.name = 'Camera_360'

# Turn the camera into an omnidirectional one.
cam.data.type = 'PANO'
cam.data.cycles.panorama_type = 'EQUIRECTANGULAR'

# Set the rendering range: every object between the two bounds below will be rendered.
cam.data.clip_start = 0.0
cam.data.clip_end = 1000.0
# The upper bound should be specified for each blender project:
# `1000` may represent a large distance in one project and a small one somewhere else.

# List of camera resolutions.
# resolutions = [(512, 256), (1024, 512)]
resolutions = [(512, 256)]

# List of camera positions in the scene.
camera_coordinates = [(0, 0, 1)]

# Define the camera field of view.
cam.data.cycles.latitude_min = (- np.pi / 2.0)
cam.data.cycles.latitude_max = np.pi / 2.0
cam.data.cycles.longitude_min = (- np.pi)
cam.data.cycles.longitude_max = np.pi

# Define the camera rotation.
# The rotation follows the rule of the right hand.
cam.rotation_euler[0] = np.pi / 2.0     # Along x.
cam.rotation_euler[1] = 0.0             # Along y.
cam.rotation_euler[2] = 0.0             # Along z.

# Specify the device.
computation_type = 'CUDA'
gpu_id = (3,)

# Set the number of rendering samples.
# bpy.context.scene.cycles.samples = 5000
bpy.context.scene.cycles.samples = 50

# Select the computing device.
prefs = bpy.context.preferences.addons['cycles'].preferences
devices = prefs.get_devices()
if computation_type == 'CUDA':
    bpy.context.scene.cycles.device = 'GPU'
    prefs.compute_device_type = 'CUDA'
    for i, gpu in enumerate(devices[0]):
        gpu.use = (i in gpu_id)

# Assign the new camera to the scene.
bpy.context.scene.camera = cam

# Activate the use of nodes.
bpy.context.scene.use_nodes = True

# Render an image for any pair ((width, height), (x, y, z)).
for width, height in resolutions:
    for x, y, z in camera_coordinates:

        # Set the camera parameters.
        bpy.context.scene.render.resolution_percentage = 100
        bpy.context.scene.render.resolution_x = int(width)
        bpy.context.scene.render.resolution_y = int(height)
        bpy.context.scene.camera.location.x = float(x)
        bpy.context.scene.camera.location.y = float(y)
        bpy.context.scene.camera.location.z = float(z)
        tree = bpy.context.scene.node_tree
        links = tree.links
        rl = tree.nodes.new(type="CompositorNodeRLayers")

        # Depth map.
        fileDepthOutput = tree.nodes.new(type="CompositorNodeOutputFile")
        fileDepthOutput.format.file_format = 'OPEN_EXR'
        fileDepthOutput.base_path = 'outputImages/{w}_{h}'.format(w=width, h=height)
        fileDepthId = 'test_{x}_{y}_{z}_{w}_{h}_depth_'.format(x=x, y=y, z=z, w=width, h=height)
        fileDepthOutputSocket = fileDepthOutput.file_slots.new(fileDepthId)
        links.new(rl.outputs['Depth'], fileDepthOutputSocket)

        # Texture.
        fileTextureOutput = tree.nodes.new(type="CompositorNodeOutputFile")
        fileTextureOutput.format.file_format = 'PNG'
        fileTextureOutput.base_path = 'outputImages/{w}_{h}'.format(w=width, h=height)
        fileTextureOutputId = 'test_{x}_{y}_{z}_{w}_{h}_'.format(x=x, y=y, z=z, w=width, h=height)
        fileTextureOutputSocket = fileTextureOutput.file_slots.new(fileTextureOutputId)
        links.new(rl.outputs['Image'], fileTextureOutputSocket)

        # Launch the rendering.
        bpy.ops.render.render(write_still=False)

        # Clean the created nodes.
        bpy.context.scene.node_tree.nodes.remove(fileTextureOutput)
        bpy.context.scene.node_tree.nodes.remove(fileDepthOutput)
```

Answer (score 3):

The reason for that is that the compositor is disabled by default in those scenes. To enable the compositor check "Compositing" under "Post Processing" in the "Output" tab.

[image: Compositing option]

Comment: @Mattia In order to enable this by script set `bpy.context.scene.render.use_compositing = True`. Note that the project contains multiple scenes which are used in the compositor. If you want to save the image with the compositing effect, you'll have to connect your *File Output* node to the same image output that is connected to the *Composite* node (in this case the *Switch* node). Additionally you would have to enable compositing, adjust the resolution and place the camera for the other scenes as well.